# Swimming lane line shadow

Tags: optics, water, refraction, shadow

In an indoor pool, I have noticed a distinctive shadow of the swimming lane lines on the bottom of the pool, whereas people swimming there do not leave shadows.

No shadows of the swimmers can be understood, considering many light sources on the ceiling and light refraction on the ripples.

But why do the lane lines leave shadows?

Comment: Do floating people leave shadows?

Comment: Are the ceiling lights in rows that run parallel to the lane markers?

Comment: Does shadow moves if you shake the lane lines?

Comment: See the wave imaged at the bottom by the refraction of light:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtmI5nlPnVY  ------  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction

Comment: The concave and convex parts of surface waves play the roles of converging and diverging lenses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens